# Why are all the EC2 instances launched in the same availability zone?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an AWS elastic beanstalk environment which contains an application load balancer that has 3 availability zones.

[image]

I'm wondering why all my 3 EC2 instances launched by elastic beanstalk are located in `ap-northeast-1c`.

Is it possible to launch EC2 instances evenly in all the availability zones? I mean 1 instance per availability zone.

The *Auto Scaling Group* in the *Configuration* section of elastic beanstalk contains 3 AZs.

[image]

But as you can see from the picture above, they are all grey, which means I'm not able to edit them. This is strange.

If I open *EC2 Service* -> *Auto Scaling Group*, I found that the auto scaling group contains only 1 AZ. This is not consistent with the setting in elastic beanstalk.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Elastic Beanstalk includes an Auto Scaling group that manages the Amazon EC2 instances in your environment. You may be using only one availability zone in your auto-scaling configuration.

Go to

> Elastic Beanstalk console -> Management page for your environment ->
>   Choose Configuration -> Auto Scaling Group -> Availability Zones

Choose the number of Availability Zones to spread your environment's instances across. By default, the Auto Scaling group launches instances evenly across all usable zones.

For full steps and further understanding

[Auto Scaling Group for Your AWS Elastic Beanstalk Environment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.managing.as.html)

EDIT: Try Auto Scaling Group under Configuration > Network and select the subnet

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. But the AZs in my auto scaling group are all grey. This means that I can't edit them.

Comment: @Brian Try Auto Scaling Group under Configuration > Network and select the subnet/AZ mappings

Comment: Hi, thank you. Changing subnet/AZ works. The instance subnets contained only 1 availability zone. I changed it to contain 3 AZs. And now my EC2 instances can be launched in different AZs.